# WordPress - Добавить пост в свою верстку

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms

Здравствуйте. Объясните кто-нибудь каким образом можно добавлять и редактировать посты если идет речь о интеграции своей верстки на WP. В То есть в файле index.php вставлен весь код своей верстки, но тогда теряются основные свойства движка WordPress. Каким образом можно отдельные текстовые блоки соединись с записями в движке. Чтобы из админки можно было изменить текст в своей верстке.

Answer (score 2):

Все до *контентной* части сунете в `header.php`,
саму *контентную* часть (новости) оставляете в `index.php`,
а то, что дальше в `footer.php`.
В `index.php` вначале нужно написать `<?php get_header(); ?>`
а в конце `<?php get_footer(); ?>`.
Перед тегом `</head>` в header.php написать `<?php wp_head(); ?>`, а перед тегом `</body>` в `footer.php` - `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`.

Файл index.php должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> <!-- подключение шапки -->

  <div class="content">
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <!-- post -->
            <div class="items"> <!-- блок новости -->
              <?php the_post_thumbnail();?> <!-- поддержка миниатюр -->
              <h1><?php the_title();?></h1></a> <!-- название статьи -->
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?> <!-- поддержка короткого описания -->
            </div>

          <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- post navigation -->
          <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no posts found -->
          <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?> <!-- подключение футера -->
```

[Для картинок (the_post_thumbnail())](http://wp-kama.ru/function/the_post_thumbnail)

[Для цитат (the_excerpt())](http://wp-kama.ru/function/the_excerpt)

Также не забудьте о файле `functions.php`. Создайте его и внесите туда это: `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`

P.S. это минимизирована версия вывода новостей..

Answer (score 1):

Всё сделано не правильно. Изменение файла index.php ядра ВП означает (в вашем случае) полное отключение ВП.
Файлы ядра вообще ни в коем случае трогать нельзя (есть оч редкие исключения. Напр исправление обнаруженной проблемы до выхода новой версии ВП с исправленной проблемой).

Не ВП помещать в свою верстку, а свою версту "натягивать" на ВП.
Делается это относительно просто. Достаточно базовых знаний php/css и изучения ссылок данных по тексту ниже.

Выбирается современная обновляемая [тема](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/), похожая по структуре. 
Создаётся [дочерняя тема](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), в которой правятся [шаблоны](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) и стили.

Ещё в помощь: [Создание тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC), [Справочник по функциям](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC)

Comment: В ответе, насколько я понял, речь идет не о главном index.php, а о файле Index.php в папке шаблона.